# Celery to manage java tasks

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a java client that communicates with celery using rabbitmq and sends the task to celery server for adding 2 numbers **x** and **y**

```
String QUEUE_NAME = "celery";
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
String x = "5";
String y = "10";
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
String ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
String message = "{\"id\":\""+ID+"\", \"task\": \"tasks.add\", \"args\": ["+x+","+y+"], \"kwargs\": {}, \"retries\": 0, \"eta\": \"2009-11-17T12:30:56.527191\"}";
channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
        .contentType("application/json").contentEncoding("utf-8")
        .build(), message.getBytes("utf-8"));
System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
channel.close();
connection.close();
```

We have a python api add to add these number and that is managed by celery.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I would like to write this `add(x,y)` function in java that celery somehow identify a java `add(x,y) method` and manage it.

Note: I am looking for a solution without webhooks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about using [celery.execute.delay_tas] (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.execute.html#celery.execute.delay_task). using this you can call task using tasks name

Comment: How celery will know that this task name is for this java function? that's the original question

Comment: so you want to have some java code that sends a task to rabbitmq, and you want celery to identify the task as being written in java an run the appropriate java code?

Comment: I already have java code which send task to celery, its a json task and which has the method name to be executed, now i want celery to read the method name and link this to corresponding java method and execute that method .

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://crabhi.github.io/celery-java/

It's a (very alpha at the moment) implementation of Celery client and worker for JVM.

You can annotate your task class:

```
 import org.sedlakovi.celery.Task;

 @Task
 public class TestTask {

     public int sum(int x, int y) {
         return x + y;
     }
 }
```

And then call the task like this:

```
Client client = new Client(rabbitConnectionChannel, rabbitBackend);

Integer result = TestTaskProxy.with(client).sum(1, 7).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

from celery import Celery
from celery import bootsteps
from kombu import Consumer, Exchange, Queue

queue = Queue("input.queue", Exchange("default"), "input.key")

app = Celery(broker="amqp://")


# Decalring the general input message handler
class InputMessageHandler(object):
    def handle(self, body):
        body_json = json.loads(body)
        _type = body_json["type"]
        if _type == "ETL":
            ETLMessageHandler().handle(body_json)


# Declaring the ETL message handler
class ETLMessageHandler(object):
    def handle(self, body):
        print("Working on ETL for message: {0}".format(body))
        # Calling out your Celery tasks here


# Declaring the bootstep for our purposes
class InputMessageConsumerStep(bootsteps.ConsumerStep):
    def get_consumers(self, channel):
        return [Consumer(channel,
                         queues=[queue],
                         callbacks=[self.handle_message],
                         accept=["json"])]

    def handle_message(self, body, message):
        InputMessageHandler().handle(body)
        message.ack()


app.steps["consumer"].add(InputMessageConsumerStep)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.start()
```

[image]

[image]